# How can I detect a throwing a ball gesture with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, computer-vision

I would like to make a website that [takes in video from the user's webcam](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). When the user performs a gesture of throwing a ball like a baseball or a football in the video, the website will play a sound.

Do you have a suggestion for JavaScript technology to use to make this? I would imagine machine learning or a computer vision library might be useful, but I haven't used either and don't want to go too far down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. A Computer Vision library like OpenCV would definitely help your cause. 
However, if you're hell-bent on subverting that entire process and using a JS framework to do the same, I have a couple of suggestions:

1. https://medium.com/@muehler.v/simple-hand-gesture-recognition-using-opencv-and-javascript-eb3d6ced28a0: This will pretty much tell you everything you need to know about gesture recognition using OpenCV and Javascript.
2. https://trackingjs.com/: This is a pretty neat library that might help you with computer vision algorithms and might spark an idea.
3. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-more-prevalent-hand-gesture-recognition-algorithms: This might definitely help.

I would love to see what happens with your project so do share your updates.